# knockoutjs ko.observableArray not displaying data when bound

Tags: knockout.js

The following data is in `ko.observableArray` **cars**: (this is the dump of the array)

```
[
  {
    "carId": 1,
    "carName": "Ford",
    "carStatus": "On-Hold",
    "carDescription": "This is the first car description."
  },
  {
    "carId": 1,
    "carName": "Toyota",
    "carStatus": "On-Hold",
    "carDescription": "This is the second car description."
  }
]
```

**View**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: cars()">
    <li>       
        <span data-bind="text: carDescription"></span>    
   </li>
</ul>
```

However, nothing is output, there are no list items showing.

Comment: Can you maybe put together a JSFiddle which shows your issue? But the `foreach: cars()` feels strange because foreach unwraps observable automatically. Try with `<ul data-bind="foreach: cars">`

Comment: While the use of `foreach: cars()`, instead of `foreach: cars`, is not recommended it won't prevent rendering.  Here is a fiddle that shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/UzC38/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle created using samples from this official tutorial http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections

http://jsfiddle.net/vgYC7/

And this is all you need to have for ViewModel

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Editable data
    self.cars = ko.observableArray([
      {
        "carId": 1,
        "carName": "Ford",
        "carStatus": "On-Hold",
        "carDescription": "This is the first car description."
      },
      {
        "carId": 1,
        "carName": "Toyota",
        "carStatus": "On-Hold",
        "carDescription": "This is the second car description."
      }
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```